# Determine if StructureMap has a specific type configured?

Tags: structuremap

Is there a way to determine if a specific type has been configured in StructureMap?

I want to return a generic type if it has not be specifically configured in StructureMap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In v2.6 you want:

```
IContainer.Model.HasImplementationsFor(serviceType)
```

Comment: or ObjectFactory.Model.HasImplementationsFor(serviceType)

Answer (score 4):

From StructureMap version 2.5.1 there is a `TryGetInstance<T>()` and `TryGetNamedInstance<T>()` which will return the default value of `T` if `T` is not known.

Comment: If `T` is *not known* ? did u mean : if `T` is *known* ?